# Seeing my own edit from a different queue in Low Quality review queue and decided it "Looks OK"?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

I was doing reviews in the *Suggested Edits* queue and improved upon an edit from a different user.

Then when I was done reviewing in this queue I moved to the *Low Quality Posts* queue and came upon [this item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17533629): The very post I edited myself a short while ago. I now reviewed this as "looks ok", because of course I felt like my edit was enough to improve the quality of the post.

But now I am having second thoughts: Was this the right action? Or should I have skipped this item in the *Low Quality* queue to let others decide if my edit really was good enough to improve the quality of the post so that it really "looks ok"?

After all, now there is one vote towards "Looks OK" and my own vote may just tip the scales in that direction.

EDIT:

This really is no duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552) as I am not asking about when to flag as "Not an answer" at all. For the sake of the question, let's just pretend I didn't overlook twice that the item in question was posted as an answer, when really it was just another question. My problem then still remains:

If I do reviews in queue B, should I then vote on items I reviewed in queue A or should I skip them, as my vote certainly will be biased?

Comment: Did you notice that the post is a question posted as answer?

Comment: @honk: Oh... no, I did not notice that. Even worse, I reviewed this TWICE and didn't notice it. :(

Comment: What is worse, another user suggested an edit on this post (before you edited it) and it got approved :|

Comment: @honk: It got approved because I improved on this edit. That's a prime example of "if anything can go wrong, it will go wrong in the worst possible way". :/

Comment: Exactly. And this time it's all your fault ;)

Comment: @honk: Thanks. Now I'll cry myself to sleep tonight. T_T

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)

Comment: Edited the post and tried to explain why I think that this is not a duplicate.

Comment: if you're not sure, then skip it. just think what will happen if everyone bring a meta post for an item they have reviewed without certainty. Just click skip

Comment: @SagarV: That's just it. When I reviewed it, I was sure. It's only now that I have second thoughts. And honestly I don't care about what will hapen if "everyone" posts on meta about this, as I am certainly not "everyone".

Comment: If you think that is enough, just click looks ok otherwise skip it. you did it so you're one of the _everyone :p_ in case if you need clarification, ask it in dedicated chat rooms.